# Combine lists into a dictionary whilst also tallying the entries for the second list

Tags: python

I'm new to python and would really appreciate some help.

I have a list of companies and a list of professions and I would like to combine them into a dictionary while also counting how many times the same profession comes up in a given company.

I currently combine them as folows:

```py
info={}
i = iter(company)
j = iter(profession)
k = list(zip(i, j)) 
for (x,y) in k: 
    if type(y) == str:
        if x in info:
            info[x] = info[x],y 
        else:
            info[x] = y
```

This produces:

```
CompanyA: "Engineer", "Group Leader","Administrator","Engineer","Engineer"
CompanyB: "Engineer", "Group Leader","Group Leader","Group Leader","Group Leader",
etc...
```

But I would like instead of repeating the professions, to have something like:

```
CompanyA: "Engineer":3, "Group Leader":1,"Administrator":1 
CompanyB: "Engineer":1, "Group Leader":4
```

Comment: Could you provide the company and profession variables in your question to make it clearer ?

Comment: Your actual and expected outputs don't use Python dict syntax, so it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Without being able to see the declarations for *company* and *profession* it's virtually impossible to tell what's right and what's wrong

Comment: If `company` and `profession` are lists, you could do away with the assignment of `i`, `j` and `k` and just write the loop as `for x, y in zip(company, profession):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is to store the companies as keys inside the `info` dict. The values of each company key, will be a sub-dictionary, with key being the *profession* and value being how many *times* the profession is shown up.

Here is the code:

```py
#Test Data
company = ["CompanyA", "CompanyΒ", "CompanyΒ",           
           "CompanyA", "CompanyΒ", "CompanyA",           
           "CompanyΒ", "CompanyA", "CompanyΒ"]           
profession = ["Engineer", "Group Leader", "Group Leader",
              "Engineer", "Group Leader", "Engineer",    
               "Group Leader", "Group Leader", "Manager"] 

info={}

for (x,y) in zip(company, profession):
    # if company not in info, add it with the first profession 
    if x not in info:
        info[x] = {y:1} # start counting from 1
    else:
        # if profession already in company's dict, add its counter
        if y in info[x]:
            info[x][y] = info[x][y]+1
        else:
            info[x][y] = 1

print(info)
```

It prints:

```
{'CompanyA': {'Engineer': 3, 'Group Leader': 1},
'CompanyΒ': {'Group Leader': 4, 'Manager': 1}}
```

**UPDATE**

1. I start the counter from 1 instead of 0
2. I added an `else: info[x][y] = 1` so that new professions will be added correctly

Comment: Does this solution answer your problem?

Comment: I think it's fully working now. More professions will be added in a single company.